# Parallel.ForEach with lock, the performance of the loop is very slow

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

When I am using `foreach` loop or `Parallel.ForEach` with lock, the data is coming out properly but when I am using `Parallel.ForEach` with no `lock`, the data is inconsistent and data loss happens. Also If instead of the model `ApiFileItems`, if I am using each of the model item as parameter in the `Parallel.ForEach` and removing the model, the output is consistent and no loss of data.

Now with `lock` I am facing the issue is that the performance is very slow.
But when I am using `Parallel.ForEach` loop without lock, the performance is fast but the data is inconsistent and data loss happens. Now I am stuck with it for almost 4 days not getting any solution to increase the performance.

```
private static void ParallelExecution(JArray ContentNode,
    ApiFileItems apiFileItems, ApiTypeItem apiTypeItem)
{
    Parallel.Foreach(ContentNode.Values(), new ParallelOptions(){}, (rootNode) =>
    {
        lock (ContentNode)
        {
            if (rootNode.HasValues)
            {
                ParallelRootItemExecution(rootNode, apiFileItems, apiTypeItem);
            }
            else
            {
                //Log the message
            }
        }
    });
}

private static void ParallelRootItemExecution(JToken rootNode,
    ApiFileItems apiFileItems, ApiItemType apiItemType)
{
    Parallel.ForEach<JToken>(rootNode.Values(),
        new ParallelOptions() {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4}, (metaNode) =>
    {
        lock (rootNode)
        {
            bool foundValue = false;
            apiFileItems.relativeFilePath = metaNode["valueString"].ToString();
            if (!foundFolderItems.TryGetValue(apiFileItems.relativeFilePath,
                out foundValue))
            {
                foundFolderItems.TryAdd(apiFileItems.relativeFilePath, true);
                ParallelExecution((String.FormatapiFileItems.relativeGroupUrl,
                    apiFileItems.hostName, apiFileItems.publicationId,
                    apiFileItems.relativeFilePath), apiFileItems,apiItemType);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

When not using `lock` then data loss happens, and the data is not consistent.

Comment: Well, you synchronize/lock the **entire** parallel work item, in effect forcing each work item to run sequentially one after the other. Exactly as it would when not using Parallel.Foreach at all. You need to identify the code part(s) in your work item that potentially can potentially concurrently access the same resource(s)/variables/properties/fields/collections/etc, and only synchronize/lock those parts, not the entire work item. If almost the entire work item is

Comment: In what way is data messed up without the lock (what did you expect, what did you get - exemplary)? What type is `foundFolderItems`? Also, nesting `Parallel.For*` is (mostly) never a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

`Parallel.Foreach` allows each iteration of a loop to be executed in parallel. But with lock, only one iteration can run at the same time. This is like a synchronous code, but with degraded performance because it must manage the lock.

A simple solution will be to do all synchronous with a classic `foreach`.

If the performance is not satisfactory in synchronous, then you need to identify where the code can't be concurrent and lock only this part.